# twitter api using OAuth - GET friends/list

Tags: javascript, list, twitter, oauth

The point is to get the user friends list so i can get their `screen_name` and `profile_img` but I can't seem to do it right.

```
function getUserInfo() {
    log("Obter informação de "+username);
    rede.get('/1.1/users/search.json?count=1&q='+encodeURIComponent(username)).done(processUserInfo).fail(logError("procurar utilizador"));
}

function processUserInfo(response) {
    username=response[0].screen_name;
    var foto=response[0].profile_image_url;

    $('#tabela').append('<p>'+username+'</p>');
    $('#tabela').append('<img src='+foto+'>');
    $('#load').hide();
}

function getUserFriends(response) {
    log("...");
    rede.get('/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor={0}&screen_name={1}&count=200&q='+encodeURIComponent(username).done(processUserInfo));
}

function processUserFriends(response) {
    log("...");  
    updateTable();
}
```

Comment: If someone can help... The point is to get the user friends list so i can get their screen_name and profile_img but i can't seem to do it right. Thanks

Comment: **1.** You can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30403660/edit) your message, so do it instead of commenting it if you add additional relevant information and not just discussing details with other members. **2.** Ctrl+k your code!